# two results when i use oracle date

Tags: sql, oracle

i am running below sql in sql developer:

```
SELECT count(*)
from FTTH_AMS_DEVICE_METRICS DAT
where TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS)>(select start_dt from ETL_JOB_CONTROL where job_name='s_m_ftth_prfrm_fact_tbl')
and TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS)<=(select end_dt from ETL_JOB_CONTROL where job_name='s_m_ftth_prfrm_fact_tbl')
```

i get 38 million rows.

when i use hardcoded values in filter as below and run the query:

```
SELECT count(*)
from FTTH_AMS_DEVICE_METRICS DAT
where TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS)> TO_DATE('10-14-2016','MM-DD-YYYY')
and TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS)<= TO_DATE('10-15-2016','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

i am getting 12 million rows.

because i pass the date values through parameter files in informatica.

I am very much confused how to handle this and get 38 million rows when i run in Informatica.

data type for COLLECTION_TMS is timestamp and end_dt is datetime.

if you need more information on this, i will share immediately.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, what are the values for start_dt, end_dt from your subqueries?

Comment: start_dt='15-OCT-16' and end_dt='16-OCT-16'

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are exactly as you show them, then in the second query you should have  `> to_date ('10-15-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy') and <= to_date('10-16-2016', 'mm-dd-yyyy')`. You are comparing to the wrong dates.

Comment: i am comparing MM-DD-YYYY as below:where TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS)> TO_DATE('10-14-2016','MM-DD-YYYY')
and TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS)<= TO_DATE('10-15-2016','MM-DD-YYYY')

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the format masks (corrected now); what I mean is that the first should be '10-15-2016' and the second '10-16-2016'.  You are comparing to the wrong **dates**, not in the wrong "manner".

Answer (score 0):

The following is speculation, informed speculation.  The `date` data type in Oracle supports a time component.  However, when you print out the date, often the time component is removed.

I am guessing that the values in `start_dt` and `end_dt` in `ETL_JOB_CONTROL` have time components.

If so, the following query should return at least 38 million:

```
select count(*)
from FTTH_AMS_DEVICE_METRICS DAT
where TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS) > TO_DATE('10-14-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') and
      TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS) <= TO_DATE('10-16-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

If this is the case, then just determine the full value for the two columns and use that:

```
select to_char(start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       to_char(end_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from ETL_JOB_CONTROL;
```

Comment: i even run with below sql select count(*)
from FTTH_AMS_DEVICE_METRICS DAT
where TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS) > TO_DATE('10-14-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
      TRUNC(DAT.COLLECTION_TMS) <= TO_DATE('10-16-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); still i get 12 million rows only.

Comment: when i run the below: select start_dt from ETL_JOB_CONTROL where job_name='s_m_ftth_prfrm_fact_tbl'. i get answer as 15-OCT-16 00:00:00.